# How to get records that has relationship with all records in another table in many to many relationships in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using Laravel 8 and MySQL8.
I have these tables:

```
products
    id - integer
    name - string

factories
    id - integer
    name - string

factory_product
    factory_id - integer
    product_id - integer
```

As you can see the `products` table has a many-to-many relationship with the `factories` table.
Now I want to get products that are produced by all factories.

In other words, I want to select the records from `products` that has a relationship with all `factories` records.
How to do that?
I need `SQL` code.

Comment: *I want to get products that are produced by all factories.* If so then the amount of factories which produces this product is equal to total amount of factories - convert this to SQL code. Or if so then there is no factory which does not produce this product - convert this to SQL code.

Comment: @Akina no, please read the question carefully. I want to get ALL products that are produced by ALL factories. A product may not be produced by one or more factories. I want to get those that are produced by all factories

Comment: Provide the sample data and desired output for better and faster resolution.

Comment: Read documentation [Eloquent Many-to-Many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: @NishantGupta I already did it in my question. I have 3 tables. `products`, `factories`, and pivot table `factory_product`. that's all.

Comment: Please also clarify if you need sql or php code (yes, you need to decide) in the answer.

Comment: @Haridarshan I have read this document before but I have not been able to answer my question.

Comment: *no, please read the question carefully.* I have read already. Re-read my comment and understand what is written there - you just did not understand its meaning, it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM factory_product
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(factory_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM factories);
```

[dbfiddle demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=b338730cbe571a57cd326ce62adee355)

**Factories** Table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| f1 | fa |
| f2 | fb |
| f3 | fc |
| f4 | fd |
| f5 | fe |

**Product** Table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| p1 | pa |
| p2 | pb |
| p3 | pc |

**Factory_Product** Table:

| factory_id | product_id |
| --- | --- |
| f1 | p1 |
| f1 | p2 |
| f1 | p3 |
| f2 | p1 |
| f2 | p3 |
| f3 | p1 |
| f3 | p3 |
| f4 | p1 |
| f4 | p3 |
| f4 | p2 |
| f5 | p1 |
| f5 | p2 |
| f5 | p3 |

The Output my Query Producing:

| product_id |
| --- |
| p1 |
| p3 |

Comment: No, It doesn't work. it returns 0 records.

Comment: @PouyaParsaei The sample data that I created is it similar to what you are working on?

Comment: yes, it is similar to my data

Comment: @PouyaParsaei Does your factories table contains duplicate factory ids?

Comment: No, there is no duplicate id, neither in the products table nor in the factories table

Comment: @PouyaParsaei what about factory_product table does it contains duplicate records? Are all factory ids in Factory Table also present in Factory_Product table?

Comment: thank you very much, your answer was correct, my table had duplicated entries. I edited my table and it works fine. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

By use of belongsToMany relation

- here this function add in your products model

  `public function withFactories() { return $this->belongsToMany(factories::class, factory_product::class,'product_id', 'factory_id'); }`
- add function in your controller

  `$all_product = products::with('withFactories)->get();`
- here must have foreign key in factory_product table
- here you can get value of product value & Factories detail in withFactories array

Comment: No, It is wrong, this function gets all products. but I need to get the only products that are produced by all factories